# Skipping an Input after scanf()

Tags: c

In the code below, after the `scanf()` for `newMIn` it skips the `gets()` for `newLname`. I've tried relocating it to other parts but it still skips, I've also tried using `getchar()` instead of `scanf()` but it still skips the next immediate function. All other variables are strings, and this function is part of a larger program.

```
void getINF(char *newStID, char *newLname, char *newMIn,char *newFname, char *newHomeAdd, char *newCourse, char *newMumNam,char *newPopsNam  ){

    printf("Input Student ID:\n");
    gets(newStID);
    printf("Input First Name:\n");
    gets(newFname);
    printf("Input Middle Initial:\n");
    scanf(" %c", &newMIn);
    printf("Input Last Name:\n");
    gets(newLname); 
    printf("Input Home Address:\n");
    gets(newHomeAdd);
    printf("Input Course:\n");
    gets(newCourse);
    printf("Input Name of Mother:\n");
    gets(newMumNam);
    printf("Input Name of Father:\n");
    gets(newPopsNam);

    printf("\n\n%s\n",newStID);
    printf("%s\n",newFname);
    printf("%c\n",newMIn);
    printf("%s\n",newLname);
    printf("%s\n",newHomeAdd);
    printf("%s\n",newMumNam);
    printf("%s\n",newPopsNam);
    printf("%s\n",newCourse);

    return;
}
```

Comment: First, never use the unsafe `gets()` function. It was deprecated in C99 and completely removed from the language in C11. Second, this may be the most common question on SO. The `scanf()` function is leaving a newline character behind in the input stream which is interfering with the call to `gets()`. You need to remove the newline from the input stream. Better, don't mix `scanf()` with other input functions.

Comment: So I should just either use fgets() or scanf() on their own?

Comment: One solution that is often convenient is to use `fgets()` to fetch user input, then `sscanf()` to parse the input. You could also use `strtol()` to convert the string obtained from `fgets()` to an integer. Alternatively, you may be able to stick with `scanf()` everywhere. Most `scanf()` conversion specifiers automatically skip leading whitespace (except for `%c`, `%[]`, and `%n`), so the extraneous newline is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

When using the `%c` token with `scanf`, it will not consume any extra whitespace of newline characters. As such, the newline character after pressing enter is left in the input buffer and then consumed by the following `gets` call.

Answer (score 0):

Use this popular method to clear the input before the next newline:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

Comment: If this is simple... another reason to avoid `scanf()`. Or just use the idiomatic and reliable `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { continue; }`.

Comment: @DavidBowling That's the other I came up with but it's more characters to type (on a 5.5" phone). Anyway, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Good thing we don't have to write code on our phones, yet... ;)

Comment: `scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");` fails to consume anything  if  the first character is a `'\n'`.  Recommend to not use that.